# How to add ssh-keys via GitHub's v3 API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to add an ssh key via GitHub's v3 API, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I'm doing is based on the instructions given [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#create-a-public-key).

More specifically, I'm using the following:

```
KEY=$( cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub )
TITLE=${KEY/* }
# the '/* ' above deletes every character in $KEY up to and including the last
# space.

JSON=$( printf '{"title": "%s", "key": "%s"}' "$TITLE" "$KEY" )

TOKEN=$( cat /path/to/tokenfile )

curl -s -d "$JSON" "https://api.github.com/user/keys?access_token=$TOKEN"
```

When I run the above, the response I get is:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

...and, sure enough, when I check in my GitHub account, `$KEY` is not among the ssh-keys listed<sup>1</sup>.

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional details**

I get the same `"message": "Not Found"` response if I just run

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/user/keys?access_token=$TOKEN"
```

If I replace the `-s` above with `-i` I see that, indeed, the returned status is `404 Not Found`.  And yet, the returned status for

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/user/keys"
```

is `401 Unauthorized`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I know that the access token in `$TOKEN` is fine, and therefore it is not the reason for the `"message": "Not Found"` response, because

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=$TOKEN"
```

returns the correct information, and

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/user/repos"
```

returns

```
{
  "message": "Requires authentication"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does your access token have "user" scope? A relevant [excerpt from the docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#list-your-public-keys):

> Management of public keys via the API requires that you are authenticated through basic auth, or OAuth with the ‘user’ scope.

If your token does **not** have "user" scope, you will get a 404 response with a message of "Not Found".

To see the scopes associated with your tokens, use the "Authorizations" API:

```
curl -u <username> https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

In the example response below, the first authorization has "user" scope, but the second one does not.

```
enter code here
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations/123",
    "app": {
      "name": "Foo",
      "url": "https://foo.example.com/",
      "client_id": "REDACTED-ID-1"
    },
    "token": "REDACTED-TOKEN-1",
    "note": null,
    "note_url": null,
    "created_at": "2013-02-18T18:24:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-05-06T14:17:00Z",
    "scopes": [
      "repo",
      "user"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations/456",
    "app": {
      "name": "Bar",
      "url": "https://bar.example.com/",
      "client_id": "REDACTED-ID-2"
    },
    "token": "REDACTED-TOKEN-2",
    "note": "for stuff",
    "note_url": null,
    "created_at": "2013-04-16T12:20:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-05-13T21:28:00Z",
    "scopes": [
      "public_repo"
    ]
  }
]
```

If you determine that this is the source of your problem, then you can resolve it in one of two ways:

- [Create a new token](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization) that has "user" scope, or
- [Update your existing token](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#update-an-existing-authorization) to add the "user" scope to it: `"add_scopes": [ "user" ]`

Comment: Thanks, that was an extremely helpful answer!

Answer (score 8):

As of February 2014 the "user" scope no longer provides enough access to manage a user's SSH keys.  The scope must be defined as:

- read:public_key - provides read access to the user’s SSH keys
- write:public_key - allows an app to read existing keys and create new ones
- admin:public_key - enables an app to read, write, and delete keys