# Can you use a Github App generated UAT (user access token) as authentication for the create a public ssh key endpoint in Github API?

Tags: github, access-token, github-api

I'm working on a project where it doesn't make sense to make users generate a personal access token. There's too much room for user error because they have to select the right permissions and manually copy paste.

I'd much prefer authenticating via a Github App. There are docs on how to do this and I've verified they do work: https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-user-access-token-for-a-github-app#using-the-web-application-flow-to-generate-a-user-access-token

Essentially, you send the user to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=<GITHUB_APP_CLIENT_ID> where all they have to do is click a big green approve button, which we can then configure to redirect to a server endpoint (Github prefills a query parameter for whatever callback endpoint you specify). Using that `code` query param, you can then make a post request to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token with the body

```
{
    "client_id": "fohgljbgkjsfbglfghdif",
    "client_secret": "sd,gjhralighrlgugfiljdgkdfgdifydfighidsds",
    "code": "dgusifughodshgodlsbvjdbv"
}
```

which I have manually verified works and returns

```
access_token=ghu_sfiuhdsuighfdisbgsdgdhsdshjsdfshdjf&expires_in=28800&refresh_token=ghr_fhiugigudsgisugdigusdig&refresh_token_expires_in=15724800&scope=&token_type=bearer
```

Recall, my original goal was to add ssh keys via this endpoint https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/keys?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-public-ssh-key-for-the-authenticated-user

Using the aforementioned token I receive the following response:

```
/tmp % curl -L -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ghu_sfiuhdsuighfdisbgsdgdhsdshjsdfshdjf" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/user/keys -d '{"title":"ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA","key":"2Sg8iYjAxxmI2LvUXpJjkYrMxURPc8r+dB7TJyvv1234"}'
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/users/keys#create-a-public-ssh-key-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

When I google this error the issue seems to be related to token permissions. I control the Github App so this seems like something that can be easily remedied but the key almost certainly has `write:public_key` scope which is the only thing the docs require. So what am I missing?

This question does not solve my problem because it was created and answered before Github changed token permissions in general and for the api in question [How to add ssh-keys via GitHub's v3 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672507/how-to-add-ssh-keys-via-githubs-v3-api)

For reference, this is the github app confirmation screen so you can see that the token generated from this flow *should* allow me to use the ssh key endpoint
[image]

Comment: this is just an idea, but I recall that the option for `Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation` was unchecked in my app (Requests that the installing user grants access to their identity during installation of your App)... not sure if knowing the user's identity might be necessary for ssh keys to be added on their behalf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app was configured with the wrong account permission. SSH signing keys are not the ssh keys you add to github to clone via ssh, those are "Git SSH keys"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the following header on the call?

```
'x-accepted-github-permissions': '{your permissions}',
```

- https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/using-the-rest-api/troubleshooting-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#resource-not-accessible
- https://github.blog/changelog/2023-08-10-x-accepted-github-permissions-header-for-fine-grained-permission-actors/

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/using-the-rest-api/troubleshooting-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#resource-not-accessible